# Querying collection inside collection based on slug

Tags: graphql, contentful

I am using Contentful for my CMS with graphql querying

Currently my API structure is `/project/:projectSlug/:jobSlug`

I have parent collection(Projects) which I need to filter by slug(projectSlug) and then also filter jobs collection filtering by slug(jobSlug).

Is there any way to get specific job and to avoid transferring all the data and filtering on the server again? If there is a solution with querying jobsCollection first and using linkedFrom I am also keen to this solution. But I couldn't get it to work.

Current model references jobs from project and last resort is changing the model.

Please advise if there are any possibilities and which would the best.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your Contentful structure? How do you query it in your project?

Comment: Using graphql, someone remove the tag from question